# Disable Joomla Account Details Email (To User)

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

Trying to disable the "Account Details for User at Site Name" email from Joomla 1.5. I commented out the following line of code and it's **still** sending:

components/com_user/controller.php:519

```
JUtility::sendMail($mailfrom, $fromname, $email, $subject, $message);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's for the frontend registration. If you want to disable those emails when you register a user from the backend, you have to edit code in `administrator/components/com_user/controller.php:189`

It's a pitty that the only way to accomplish this in 1.5 is hacking of core files...